# How to transform filtered polymorphic sites (in fasta format) into binary matrix in R?

Tags: r, fasta, binary-matrix

Thank you in advance for your help...

I want to create a binary matrix from filtered polymorphic sites. I have the the WGS assemblies in fasta format, one file for each isolate sequenced (131 fasta files in total).

For examples a fasta file contains *x*  number of elements each a different length. Using the package seqinr the file is read in as shown below with the number of nodes corresponding to the number of elements in each file;
fasta1$Node_1_length_179262_cov_53.4208_ID_3720: Class 'SeqFastadna' a a t c... 
fasta1$Node_2_length_151612_cov_41.7317_ID_3726: Class 'SeqFastadna' a t t t...

I also have an excel document containing the filtered_polymorphic_sites(the polymorphic loci found in the wgMLST analysis with all loci subject to recombination filtered out)(performed by Gubbins).
e.g. Isolate 1: CGTGAGCCGCGG-AGCCAATAGGGTCAGTGCGGTCGCTGCGGGGTGAACGGCGCAAGCTTTGTCACGCCGGATGGAAGTATGGCCCAGAATTGTTTTTTTATGCGGGCGGGGCTGGCACGAGAAACGATGC

Isolate 2: CGTGAGCCGCGG-AGCCAATAGGGTCAGTGCGGTCGCTGCGGGGTGAACGGCGCAAGCTTTGTCACACCGGATGGAAGTATGGCCCAGAATTGTTTTTTTATTCGGGCGGGGCTGGCACAAGAAGCGATGC

I would prefer to do this in R, so if you could suggest an R-package, that would be amazing, however all suggestions welcome.

Many thanks!!

Comment: Can you show some data? From the question, the solution might be in coding the sites `as.factor` and changing the `levels` to 0, 1.

Comment: Try looking at adegenet package, you might find something useful there.

Comment: The adegenet package looks very useful, thank you @din, however in the end I used SplitsTree.

Comment: @sruby52, did you end up with a binary matrix with rows as 
 isolates (samples) and columns as positions (bases) which 1 if similar to a reference and 0 if not similar to the reference? And did you concatenate all the polymorphic sites to form one matrix? or you did you make one matrix for each locus?